# Unable to change Menu title in jQuery (MeanMenu)

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the MeanMenu jQuery Responsive menu plugin for the navigation on my web page. Everything seems to work well, but I can't figure out how to change the title of the menu when it's closed. I just want to add the word "Menu" to the three bars or replace the three bars with this word. This is the line from the .js file:

```
meanMenuOpen: "<span /><span /><span />", // text/markup you want when menu is closed, styling in CSS provides 3 bars with these spans
```

I filled the line like this:

```
meanMenuOpen: "<span />Menu<span /><span />", // text/markup you want when menu is closed, styling in CSS provides 3 bars with these spans
```

The CSS for this part looks like this:

```
.mean-container a.meanmenu-reveal span {
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    height: 3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

But my solution isn't showing. How can I fix that? Thank you for your help!

Comment: please don't post links to your entire project. post http://sscce.org/ examples in http://jsbin.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. :)

Comment: I edited my original post and removed the link to my project. I hope you can help me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Thanks to help with King's answer.

jquery.meanmenu.js

```
meanMenuOpen: "<span /><span /><span /><div class='menu_title'>Menu</div>", // text/markup you want when menu is closed
```

CSS

```
.menu_title {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    bottom:1em;
    margin-right:2em;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The SPAN's refer to the hamburger icon. Whilst this might not be pretty code it works how you describe and I have tested it on the popular browsers;

CSS

```
.menu_title {
   display: block;
   position:relative;
   float:right;
   height: 1em;
   bottom:.65em;
   margin-right:2.5em;  
}
```

HTML

```
<header>
<nav>
<div class="menu_title">Menu</div>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Top Level Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Top Level Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Top Level Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Top Level Link</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

I also use foundation 4's visibility classes to hide it for medium screens up (hide-for-medium-up) but a media query of;

```
@media all and (min-width:768px){

.menu_title{
   display:none !important; 
   visibility:hidden;
   }

}
```

Works the same.